# Execute a command line on the command prompt needs `administrate privilege` even using "ranas"?

Tags: windows-7, command-prompt, netsh, privilege

This is the command:

```
 netsh wlan start hostednetwork runas /noprofile /user:mymachine\\administrator
```

I used `ranas` to prevent the administrator privilege, but it won't.

[image]

But when I manually run the command prompt as an administrator and write `netsh wlan start hostednetwork` it will execute the command.

[image]

---

I am sending this command from Java program, I can't run the command prompt as an administrator then write this command, It should be in one line command that do all works.

Any solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe what you are looking for is:

`runas /noprofile /user:mymachine\administrator "netsh wlan start hostednetwork"`

you just got the order of your commands switched on accident.

Comment: I tried this, it give me this message `Enter the password for mymachine\\administrator:`, and just `ENTER` key works, I can't not type any password.

Comment: type in the password for that account and press `ENTER`. It doesn't show the password as you type it. Also there was an extra slash in there. you want `mymachine\administrator` not `mymachine\\administrator`. I didn't notice that when i copied your code, but the answer above has been updated.